# 【ldconfig】/sbin/ldconfig: Renaming of /etc/ld.so.cache~ to /etc/ld.so.cache failed: No such file or directory

Tags: linux

After my process is started, I create an so soft link in the /usr/local/lib/ directory, such as`liba.so -> liba_onlyme.so`.

To enable subsequent processes to use liba.so, I need to invoke ldconfig to refresh the lib cache. However, an error is reported,
`/sbin/ldconfig: Renaming of /etc/ld.so.cache~ to /etc/ld.so.cache failed: No such file or directory`

I want to know why.

Comment: the problem has been solved，multi user exec ldconfig at the same time reseult in the problem，ldconfig implementation has the action to delete dir.

Comment: what exactly did you do to resolve this? Can you please post the answer.